# In a DataGridView one column has a filename I want a button in each row to allow the user to input/change the filename and path

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

The `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataSet`. Let's say there is only one column for this example. The 1 column is filename. For each row I need to open the `FileOpenDialog` to change or update the filename column. How do I add the button? does it have to be in a separate column or can it be in the same colum?

Answer (score 0):

Add another unbound column and use `DataItemTemplate` to add button for each row. On `Button_Click` event, open the `FileOpenDialog` and while opening you can pass the value of file name which is in the same row's column 0.